# Kendo Grid onLoad Javascript error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo grid and On page load giving error  in jquery-1.4.3.min.js in IE8 as below:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'length' is null or not an object

even i have changed jquery version to 1.7.1.min but it still giving me error.

Help me!!!

thanks,
Ravi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what version of Kendo you are using, different versions require different minimum versions of jQuery.

If you are using the latest Q3 2012 release then jQuery 1.8.2 is required. Before that 1.7.1 should be sufficient.

Of course, the error might have nothing to do with Kendo and could be coming from your own code, but unless you post an example code or a minimal stack trace it's impossible to tell.